# TempData becomes null after refresh the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, tempdata

I used TempData to pass data from an action to another,but when i refresh the page 
the value of TempData becomes null,
how I can solve this probleme?
Thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `Session` instead of `TempData`. TempData is supposed to be used only for a single redirect. Another possibility is to call the [Keep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.keep.aspx) method inside the controller action in which you are consuming the value from TempData. This way if the user refreshes the page by hitting F5 TempData will be persisted for one more request.

Comment: I have in the controller in which i consume value of TempData: TempData["data"]="consumerId"; how can i use Keep(), thanks Darin

Comment: The example you have shown is writing to TempData, not reading (consuming). You need to call the Keep method inside the controller action in which you use TempData's value.

Comment: excuse me its like this  string consumerId = (string)TempData["data"];

Comment: Yeap, it's like this. It is inside this controller action that you need to call the Keep method.

Comment: Keep() doesn't existe I'm adding reference Systeme.web.mvc but nothing

Comment: Inside the controller action you call: `TempData.Keep();`.

Comment: Like this: System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary.Keep(consumerId );

Comment: NO! `Keep` is an instance method as shown in the documentation I have linked to. This means that you need to call it on an instance of `TempDataDictionary`. Inside the controller action you write `TempData.Keep();`.

Comment: You can also use Keep to retain a single Key of a tempdata with .Keep(Key)