# Data source not bound error in MVC 4 WebGrid upon refresh. TempData reseting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid, tempdata

I have an MVC 4 application that displays a list of results from a search in a WebGrid. The results page loads correctly displaying all of the data matching the search. If I reload the page I get...

```
"A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed."
```

I am not display the WebGrid is a partialView, as I have seen questions similar to this with relation to a partial view. Anyone have an idea as to why a refresh would cause a loss of data?

**EDIT:**

Here is my controller method for the Results page.

```
public ActionResult Results()
    {
        var model = TempData["Results"] as List<iCap.Business.Complaint>;

        return View(model);
    }
```

I noticed TempData["Results"] resets upon refresh. Is there anyway to prevent that?

Thanks always,

Rock

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11194300/2682614. TempData does reset upon refresh so I am now using seesion instead.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchView search)
    {
        Session["Results"] = null;
        var results = RCCADao.RCCASearch(search);
        Session["results"] = results;

        return RedirectToAction("Results");
    }

    public ActionResult Results()
    {
        var model = Session["Results"] as List<iCap.Business.Complaint>;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Hope this helps anybody else with a similar problem!

Rock